# how to turn curl specification into httr code

Tags: r, httr

I think I'm missing something in my translation of this curl:

```
curl -X POST \
https://api.some.url
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-H 'apiKey: MyAppApiKey' \
-d 'username=MyAppUsername&to=%2B1XXXXXXXXXX&message=Hello%20World!&from=myShortCode'
```

Into this `httr` code:

```
POST(url = "https://api.some.url", 
     config = list(add_headers(apiKey = MyAppApiKey)),
     body = list(username = MyAppUsername,
                 to = "%2B1XXXXXXXXXX",
                 message = "Hello%20World!",
                 from = myShortCode),
     encode = "form"
)
```

I'm getting a 401 code, which the gateway does not list as a recognized code. I don't have a lot of API experience, so I'm wondering if I'm missing a key step.

**Update 1:**

I took @QHarr's suggestion and tried suggestion. Here is the suggested httr code:

```
headers = c(
  `Accept` = 'application/json',
  `Content-Type` = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  `apiKey` = api_key
)

data = list(
  `username` = user_name,
  `to` = '%2B25479XXXXXXX',
  `message` = 'Hello',
  `from` = '22XXX'
)

res <- httr::POST(url = url_alt, 
                  httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), 
                  body = data)
```

I'm getting a 405 error. I checked with someone at the gateway, and they replied:

> what we are receiving seems not to be in that format, below is the body we are getting

```
Body: --------------------------3cd74f6953XXXXXX
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="username"
XXXXX
--------------------------3cd74f6953XXXXXX
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="to"
%2B25479XXXXXXX
--------------------------3cd74f6953XXXXXX
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="message"
Hello
--------------------------3cd74f6953XXXXXX
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="from"
22XXX
--------------------------3cd74f6953XXXXXX--
```

I'm not sure what to make of this. Any ideas?

Comment: Try pasting curl into this: https://curl.trillworks.com/#r and viewing httr (R) output. Perhaps config takes care of the differences?

Comment: Not working yet, but this is a fantastic resource!! Thanks @QHarr